# Why is Python giving me "an integer is required" when it shouldn't be?

Tags: python, file, load, pickle

I have a save function within my Python program which looks like this:

```
def Save(n):
    print("S3")
    global BF
    global WF
    global PBList
    global PWList
    print(n)
    File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\BF.txt", "w")
    pickle.dump(BF, File)
    File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\WF.txt", "w")
    pickle.dump(WF, File)
    File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\PBList.txt", "w")
    pickle.dump(PBList, File)
    File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\PWList.txt", "w")
    pickle.dump(PWList, File)
```

Here, n is "1".

I get an error looking like this:

```
  File "C:/Python27/KingsCapture.py", line 519, in Save
    File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\BF.txt", "w")
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Upon doing the same loading within the shell, I get no errors:

```
>>> File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Test\List.txt", "r")
>>> File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Test\List.txt", "w")
>>> n = "1"
>>> File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\BF.txt", "r")
>>> File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\BF.txt", "w")
```

Why is this having a problem?

Comment: Change `print(n)` to `print(repr(n), type(n))`.  The output may be enlightening.

Comment: In Python `UpperCase` is for classes and `lower_case` is for variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably did a star import from the os module:

```
>>> open("test.dat","w")
<open file 'test.dat', mode 'w' at 0x1004b20c0>
>>> from os import *
>>> open("test.dat","w")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

so you're using the wrong open function.  (I suppose you could've simply done `from os import open`, but that's less likely.)  In general this import style should be avoided, as should use of `global`, where practical.

Comment: +1, or possibly just thought that `from os import open` was necessary

Comment: @gnibbler: I was just editing to comment on that but you beat me to it. :^)

Comment: That's exactly what it was, thanks. I had from os import * because of an error I had earlier, and I forgot to get rid of it. -facepalm-
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape your strings: a \ in a string is an escape character.

Either escape the slashes:

```
"C:\\KingsCapture\\Test\\List.txt"
```

or use Raw strings:

```
r"C:\KingsCapture\Test\List.txt"
```

Comment: That's a good point, I forgot about those with the others. Although that wasn't what was causing the problem, I should change that as well. :P Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As DSM noted, you're using http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.open instead of built-in open() function.

In os.open() the second parameter (mode) should be integer instead of string. So, if you ought to use `from os import *` then just substitute mode string with one of the following args:

- os.O_RDONLY
- os.O_WRONLY
- os.O_RDWR
- os.O_APPEND
- os.O_CREAT
- os.O_EXCL
- os.O_TRUNC

Comment: Actually, with that import, he wouldn't need "os." for the constants.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that n is `1` not `"1"`.

try:

```
print(type(n))
```

I'll guess that you'll see its an `int` not a string.

```
File = open("C:\KingsCapture\Saves\\" + n + "\BF.txt", "w")
```

You can't add ints and strings producing the error message you are getting.

Comment: Adding an int to a string would produce `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` in Python 2.7, I think.

Comment: I specifically set n to be "1", "2", "3", or "4", depending on the button that is pressed