# Calling io.open(), not os.open()

Tags: python

I have read [Why is Python giving me "an integer is required" when it shouldn't be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354276/why-is-python-giving-me-an-integer-is-required-when-it-shouldnt-be). It is nearly a complete solution for my issue, but not quite.

Here is my code:

```
#! usr/local/bin/python3.6
# coding: utf-8

from os import getcwd, listdir
import psycopg2
from io import open

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=ktab user=malikarumi")
cur = conn.cursor()
path = getcwd()
filenames = listdir(path)

for filename in filenames:
with open(filename, 'r', 'utf-16') as f:
    f1 = f.read()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO testable (title, content, chron_date, clock)\
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"),
    (filename, f1, '2017-12-30', '23:59:00'),

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

After reading the older SO post, I modified my code as above, so as to specify which `io` module I wanted and restrict the `os` modules to the two I was using. Sublime Text 3 has a tooltip which indicates I am calling `io.open()`, but when I run the code, it is plainly `os.open()` (I know because of the error):

```
(lifeandtimes) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/Progress_Logs/2017$
python ktab_odt4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ktab_odt4.py", line 17, in <module>
with open(filename, 'r', 'utf-16') as f:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Note: I already tried `with io.open()` and `import io`. In both cases pylint squawked and the interpreter gave me name errors. Using `'rb'` got past pylint but the interpreter still gives me the `TypeError`. What is the workaround for this situation?

Comment: Please reduce the code in your question to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @martineau: Seriously? Is that a requirement now? I ask because I have more often been taken to task for not putting **enough** code in my posts!

Comment: **Yes**, you should almost always include code, but try to provide the least amount of it that will reproduce the problem. This will allow others to reproduce the problem and test any fixes they have and it will make it more likely for you to get help quickly. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case all the psycopg2/database related stuff just gets in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third positional parameter to `io.open()` is `buffering`, which requires an integer.  You are passing the string `'utf-16'` as the third parameter, thus the error you're getting.  You need to use `encoding='utf-16'` to pass that value as a keyword parameter.

Comment: It looks like you're right. I tried it and this error goes away. Thank you. Sadly, now I have "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 260-261: illegal encoding" which seems to be in the document itself, and a different issue I will have to post about separately if I can't figure out a workaround :-(