# Python 3 on Windows: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple port scanner, or "telnet test" with Python 3 on Windows.

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when running the code.

**Output**

```
C:\Python\Codes>python test.py

Destination IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Port number: 2020
Host 127.0.0.1 port 2020
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    SCAN_TCP_PORT()
  File "test.py", line 9, in SCAN_TCP_PORT
    s.connect((DstIP, DstPort))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

C:\Python\Codes>
```

I've been googling and found this link, but it doesn't related with my problem.

[Why is Python giving me "an integer is required" when it shouldn't be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354276/why-is-python-giving-me-an-integer-is-required-when-it-shouldnt-be)

What is wrong with my code on line 9? And how to fix it?

**Error**

```
  File "test.py", line 9, in SCAN_TCP_PORT
    s.connect((DstIP, DstPort))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, socket

def SCAN_TCP_PORT():
    DstIP = input('\nDestination IP Address: ')
    DstPort = input('Port number: ')
    print ('Host %s port %s' % (DstIP, DstPort))
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((DstIP, DstPort))
    print("%s is listening on TCP port %s" % (DstIP, DstPort))

SCAN_TCP_PORT()
```

Comment: Well, there is no way that `DstIP` can be an `int`. Have you tried converting `DstPort` to `int`?

Comment: I'm new to Python sir @DeepSpace and learning it from Google. May I know how to do it?

How do you know `DstIP` is `int` and how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the value of DstPort as an integer, for example replacing your `s.connect((DstIP, DstPort))` by `s.connect((DstIP, int(DstPort)))`

Comment: Many thanks. It works! Thanks for helping. I've updated my question so that others especially new learner will learn from it as well.