# with open(filename, 'w') as fp:

Tags: python, file

I've a problem in Python with opening an ASCII file:

Code:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
```

> Error message:  "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"

I use the same construct for pickling and have no problems at all

Any suggestions?

I use Windows 7 Pro, Python 3.6.4 in PyCharm 2.7.3, Community Ed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Python giving me "an integer is required" when it shouldn't be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354276/why-is-python-giving-me-an-integer-is-required-when-it-shouldnt-be)

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks. I found the answer on a different forum. The issue is that the os-library also has an "open" method. Since I imported this library I effectively used "os.open()", rather than the regular "open()"

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what's explained in the duplicate.